# SQL Server 2014 compatibility feature is not working with 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, compatibility

I'm using SQL Server 2014 in the dev environment. But, my clients are using SQL Server 2008 and they are having problems with some scripts, like the keyword `CONCAT` which is not compatible with SQL Server 2008.

I corrected the concat problem, but how can I prevent this kind of problems.

I've tried to activate the compatibility level to : SQL Server 2008 (100)

[image]

But when I execute a query containing `CONCAT` keyword, it doesn't give me an error which it should not be recognized.

Is there something else I can configure in my SQL Server to force it to accept only **SQL Server 2008** compatible queries ?

Comment: Just develop your code on SQL2008R2 (express).

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-actual-behavior-of-compatibility-level-80

Answer (score 0):

If you change the compatibility to SQL Server 2008 (100) means all the features from SQL Server 2008 till your current instance version(in your case it is SQL Server 2014) is accessible. As of i know, there is no way to force the SQL Server to limit to use of features of SQL Server 2008 alone in SQL Server 2014 instance.

You can make the current instance to make use of earlier version features through Compatibility settings(Compatibility settings exist for this purpose only) but no way to force the instance of SQL Server 2014 to abide only to SQL Server 2008 features.

Comment: This is not normal, there must be a solution for this problem :(

Comment: Very happy to know if such one exists.

Comment: Compatibility levels provide, limited, backwards compatibility.  Sorry but they weren't designed to limit access to newer features.  Agreed this would be a handy feature.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Comment: Ok, but is there another thing I can do to achieve what I want ?

Comment: It will be hard to accept. 1) Stick to 2008 Coding Practices (or) 2) Make your DEV environment adhere to your Client Environment.

Comment: You can create a 2008 instance and move your data there (that would be a lot of work though).